# Overwritting observable/observableArray set method

Tags: knockout.js

I am in the situation where I want to overwrite the `set` method that knockout has on observables; and to give you an example why I want that, take the following example code:

```
this.magic = ko.observableArray();

// ... inside an Ajax request
var formatted = reduceAndFormat(respone);
this.magic(formatted);
```

This is repeated a couple of times, so instead I would like to move the entire body of the `reduceAndFormat` function in the `set` method of a possibly customized observable.

Is there a way to do this? because outside of subscribing to observable updates didn't see much else in the documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a [writable computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#writeable_computed_observables)

Something like this perhaps:

```
// private variable
this._magic = ko.observableArray();

// property with getter and setter
this.magic= ko.computed({
    read: function(){
        return _magic();
    },
    write: function(value) {
        var formatted = reduceAndFormat(value);
        this._magic(formatted);
    }
});
```